# Add GroupBy to Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I have this query

```
[HttpGet]
public List<AttachedPhotosModel> GetReportAttachedPhotos(int reportId)
{
  var photos = new ReportsRepository().GetInjuryPhotos(reportId);

  return photos.Select(x => new AttachedPhotosModel()
  {
    Id = x.Id,
    Type = x.InjuryType,
    Photos = photos.Where(y => y.InjuryType == x.InjuryType).Select(z => z.ServicePhotoUrl).ToList()
  }).ToList();
}
```

I need to GroupBy InjuryType, how to do this?

I added `return photos.GroupBy(k => k.InjuryType).Select(x => new AttachedPhotosModel()` but how to select model, `x` have new value `key` and I don't know how to select my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. Assuming photos is collection of objects with InjuryType property and PhotoUrl property and AttachedPhotosModel has an InjuryType and Photos properties like this.

```
public class AttachedPhotosModel
{
    public string InjuryType { set; get; }
    public List<string> Photos { set; get; }
}
```

Code for grouping by `InjurType`.

```
var grouped = photos
           .GroupBy(s => s.InjuryType,d => d.PhotoUrl, (k, g) => new
                  AttachedPhotosModel
                  {
                     InjuryType = k,
                     Photos = g.ToList()
                  }).ToList();
```